# CSS `height: auto;` taller than it needs to be. how is it computing the height?

Tags: html, css

I'm working with some HTML/CSS for an existing website built on WordPress, so there's probably something with the theme's CSS impacting this issue, but I don't see how.

There's some CSS that sets `<li>` of the mobile navigation to `height: auto;`. The text within the `<li>` is 32px tall. However, the `<li>` height is computed to 80px.

I checked for padding and margins. There are none. So I'm not sure how it's actually computing the height.

**I've posted a snippet to the code here:** https://codepen.io/kanekekoa/pen/OJdVyoP

I don't want to set the height explicitly (e.g., 32px). Is there something else I can do to get the height to be only as tall as its contents?

Comment: *I could post a snippet but I don't think it'll make much sense* --> how are we supposed to help then?

Comment: *Is there something else I can do to get the height to be only as tall as its contents?* --> everyone will start guessing and no one will get the correct answer because we have no code

Comment: `height:auto` isn't responsible for this. That will just make the element big enough for its contents, and in fact, `auto` is the intrinsic value for `height`. There must be something else which is increasing the size of your list items. Please include a snippet, or at least a link to a webpage where we can see it in action.

Comment: maybe `line-height`? anyway I agree you have to share the code or it will be a lottery betting with guesses

Comment: @TemaniAfif I'll post a snippet.

Comment: Just updated the question with this link to the snippet https://codepen.io/kanekekoa/pen/OJdVyoP @TemaniAfif :)

Comment: The [mre] must also be included in the question itself, not just rely on an external link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a setting `min-height: 5rem;` for the `li` which is responsible for the 80px height.

Comment: Goodness. How'd I miss that?! Thanks, Johannes!